# How to get diffrence b/w two times

Tags: django

I want to get the diffrence between two times as given below

class Time(models.Model):

```
start_time=models.TimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now=False,null=True)
end_time=models.TimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now=False,null=True)
```

#viewset

start_time=12:00:00

end_time=15:00:00

how to get diffrence between these two times

Comment: start= timeobject.start_time
end= timeobject.end_time

differance= end-start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert your timeFields to DateTimeFields and then you can easily perform arithmetic operations between the two fields. For example :-

```
start_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now=False,null=True)
end_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now=False,null=True)

def get_difference (self): 
  difference = self.end_time - self.start_time
  return difference.seconds
// Add additional logic to convert seconds to hours if you want to
```

The difference object would then support all of the attributes and methods offered by the python datetime.datetime library.

Comment: i am creating api,can i simply do end_time-start_time?

Comment: You would needlessly be reinventing the wheel if you write custom logic in order to get difference between to two TimeField objects as they inherently do not support arithmetic operations. DateTimeField offers you everything out of the box without any overhead.

Comment: yes,that is why i was getting error,i guess your ans would be helpfull there

Comment: @Ashutosh Mishra of the answer helped, you can choose it as the answer to close the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ***DateTimeField*** instead of ***TimeField*** ..as `time` object doesn't support comparison..

Try this..

```
class Time(models.Model):

    start_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now=False,null=True)
    end_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now=False,null=True)

    def time_difference(self):
        return self.end_time - self.start_time
```